# What is the word for being disappointed in not knowing mankind's fate?

Tags: single-word-requests

A long time ago I read about a word that means something like "The fear or disappointment that you will never know the ultimate fate of mankind and the universe and how it will all play out."

It is a very rarely used word, and I was interested to know it exists, but I have forgotten. Does anyone know what it is?

Comment: Mankind doesn’t have a plural.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ellipsism - the feeling of sadness that you will not know how history plays out.

It should be noted that this is a made up word, from a project where they aimed to name words for emotions that currently have no name. (Source: http://www.openculture.com/2019/04/words-invented-to-name-emotions-we-all-feel-but-dont-yet-have-a-name-for.html). The project is called "Dictionary of Obscure Sorrows".

Comment: This answer would benefit from a source to support it, but I cannot find any dictionary that has it.

Comment: This is the word. I can't find it in any dictionary either. So making note here that perhaps its a made up internet word that isn't actually real. Marking as correct though as this is what I was looking for and I will do further investigation into it.

Comment: After further investigation, adding that this is a made up word, from a project where they aimed to name words for emotions that currently have no name. (Source: http://www.openculture.com/2019/04/words-invented-to-name-emotions-we-all-feel-but-dont-yet-have-a-name-for.html).

The project is called "Dictionary of Obscure Sorrows". 

I have made an edit to the answer, and will accept as correct after peer review